# Who is this person? - New user with the same name as me - my name isn't that common

Tags: support

Maybe I'm being overly suspicious here, but I don't have a particularly common name, so it was a bit surprising to see a new response to an old question from this profile (https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/7070/kate-paulk), particularly since I'm not aware of anyone else with this name anywhere in the SQA community (it is my real name, incidentally).

The response also echoes my writing style somewhat, although not enough to be obviously me (https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/7865/422).

I don't know if I should be flagging it, changing my display name, or what.

Comment: Is Kate Paul such a unique name?

Comment: Kate Paul*k* is unusual.

Answer (score 1):

So I checked out the doppleganger (who has changed her name to Kate Paul, which is the name of 2010 Miss Oregon actually...) I was unable to find anything substantial.

The one post (s)he had is actually deleted now because it was a copy paste of the accept answer (although that post was in word form while the accepted answer was in bullets). So it's rather peculiar.

Obviously what this person has done is strange, but it doesn't appear to be against the rules. Especially since the name has changed to be different, even if similar. What would be against the rules would be the vaguely define 'harassment', but there doesn't appear to be any there.

Comment: Thanks, corsiKa. I've had a few issues with trolling and harassment in the writing communities (not Stack Exchange based) I'm involved in, so I was a little concerned and wanted to ask before I did anything else. It's possible the doppelganger just mistyped for a name (at least, I hope so). And yeah, it is a bit odd.

Comment: Well, it's also possible they were originally hoping to sneak in and get cheap reputation based on the name. It's hard to tell. I will certainly keep an eye on the situation, and of course if there's any kind of harassment, flag it and we'll tackle that straight away.